# Reduce key value pairs in a javascript object based on a given array

Tags: javascript

I want to remove unnecessary key values pairs in a user object based on an array, essentially a whitelist. I have looked at `reduce()`, `filter()` and `map()` but can't quite get the implementation to work.

Here is my code currently

```js
const user = {
   "email": "hello@me.com"
   "name": "Bob"
   "surname": "Smith"
};

const userFields = [`email`, `name`]; // array of whitelist
```

Before I iterate through the object properties, I'd like to reduce Object to have fields only in the array whitelist, so our man Bob Smith would end up like this

```js
const user = {
  "email": "hello@me.com" 
  "name": "Bob"
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Question: Do you want to modify the object in place, or create a new object?

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` on userFields and build

```js
const user = {
  email: "hello@me.com",
  name: "Bob",
  surname: "Smith",
};

const userFields = [`email`, `name`];

const newUser = userFields.reduce(
  (acc, key) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: user[key] }),
  {}
);
console.log(newUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the simplest thing to do would be to loop through the passlist and build an object:

```
const result = {};
for (const name of userFields) {
    result[name] = user[name];
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const user = {
   "email": "hello@me.com",
   "name": "Bob",
   "surname": "Smith",
};

const userFields = [`email`, `name`];

const result = {};
for (const name of userFields) {
    result[name] = user[name];
}

console.log(result);
```

You *could* use `map` and `Object.fromEntries`, but I don't think it buys you anything:

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(
    userFields.map(name => [name, user[name]])
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const user = {
   "email": "hello@me.com",
   "name": "Bob",
   "surname": "Smith",
};

const userFields = [`email`, `name`];

const result = Object.fromEntries(
    userFields.map(name => [name, user[name]])
);

console.log(result);
```

---

FWIW, for me `reduce` is the wrong tool for this (or indeed, *almost* anything else outside of Functional Programmning with predefined, reusable reducer functions), not least because the accumulator in a `reduce` solution would never change (it's always the same object). `reduce` where a simple loop suffices is just overcomplicated and easy to get wrong. (An opinion which [isn't](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544) [solely](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224) mine, btw.)

Comment: @VLAZ - LOL, quite. What was I thinking?!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) method. Traverse the `userFields` array using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and make a list of `key-value` pair array. At last, from that list transform it into the required object by using `Object.entries()` method.

```js
const user = {
  email: 'hello@me.com',
  name: 'Bob',
  surname: 'Smith',
};

const userFields = [`email`, `name`];
const ret = Object.fromEntries(userFields.map((x) => [x, user[x]]));
console.log(ret);
```